# Moving website from one folder to another in xcart

Tags: x-cart

i am moving website from one folder https://www.example.com/xcart_demo/xcart/ to https://www.dev.example.com, but right now it is giving error of 500 internal server error,

can anyone help how can i configure htaccess and config.php file ?

Thank You

Comment: Let me just quickly consult my crystal ball so i can see what you have tried already. Just incase that doesn't provide me with answers I also recommend you update your question with that same information.

Answer (score 2):

**If you're running X-Cart 5**, 
please follow the steps described in this article:

- http://kb.x-cart.com/en/general_setup/moving_x-cart_to_another_location.html

**If you use X-Cart 4**, 
please check these instructions:

- https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Moving_store_to_web-root_directory
- https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Moving_store_to_another_host

If none of the instructions work, please provide more details on the software version you use and steps you have already taken

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed:

```
$xcart_http_host
$xcart_https_host
```

in your xcart `config.php` file?

Comment: yes , i have configure htaccess and config file both , but unable to resolve , showing error like

Warning: require(__DIR__/top.inc.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /raid/home/bubblebag/dev/index.php on line 44

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/top.inc.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /raid/home/bubblebag/dev/index.php on line 44

is it server issue ?

Comment: I am not sure if it is an xcart issue. Try testing with some non-xcart HTML and php files to see if it works that way.